# MVC Get Control View HTML value

Tags: model-view-controller, email, view, controls

I was curious to see if its possible that from a controller (or else where) could I get a instance of a Control View pass it the model it requires and get back the html that it would output?

For example I have a Control View that builds a league table. This is fine for when using it on the site but I also want to put this league table into a html email that I send out... can I use the control view to do this or do I have to recreate the league table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the table itself in a partial view, you could easily use `Html.RenderPartial()` to get the output from it. If you go so far as having an action method that gets the appropriate data from your data store and returns the partial, you could even use `Html.Action()` (given that you use MVC2 or higher).